# Design best practice - model vs controller vs UI - CakePHP, MySQL

Tags: mysql, cakephp, design-patterns

I have been struggling for a few days with this problem and finally seek the opinion of the experts and crowd at this website.

1. I have two tables - one is a template of workflow steps and the other is an instance of these workflow steps called events. The templates table contains information like step name, step type etc - very generic information. The event table contains a reference link back to the workflow step table and an additional column called notes - which stores data that the user logged as they logged a particular workflow step. Both Workflow Steps and Events are linked to a POST on the website
2. Workflow step templates can exist without events having yet occurred - that is the user may be still on Step 3 or Step 5 and not logged an event for Step 1, 2 , 4 - basically the order of steps is only suggestive but not binding. Workflow Steps have a sequence field that dictate the order in which they should appear on screen.
3. Events can also occur without a workflow step - in other words, a user can log a note outside the context of workflow steps. These are generic events and directly associated with the POST
4. I am able to successfully retrieve both of these values for a given POST - they are retrieved as two separate arrays. I am using CakePHP and MySQL
5. The UI needs to render a screen that shows all the workflow steps in order and corresponding events that have occured in correlation to these steps or outside of these steps. The ordering of the screen will be driven primarily by the sequence of workflow steps and secondarily by created_date for those events that are not associated with a particular workflow step

Problem statement - 
1. Do I send two separate arrays (as noted in #4) to the UI and let the UI determine the complex logic of how to interweave the steps and events for display?
2. Do I process the interweaving of steps and events in the controller and then send to the UI a simple array that it can loop through and display?
3. I have tried moving this logic to the database but because of variations explained in #2 and #3 it becomes quite complicated

I am seeking advise on which would be a better option from a design practice as well as from a simplification point of view. I understand that I have given a limited picture here but am hoping that someone on this website may have run into a similar issue elsewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - I have solved this. I ended up moving the functionality to the Model.

1. I created two SQL queries - one that retrieves all the workflow steps along with any event information that maybe associated with each of them.
2. Then I created a second SQL that retrieves all those events that are stand-alone and not associated with any particular workflow step
3. I used UNION ALL to stack them on top of each other
4. I used a SORT on modified date and squence number so that all the steps and events appear in chronological order and sequence

I then passed this from the Model to the View (via the controller) and let the View iterate and display the elements. This approach actually simplified my View and Controller code immensely and even the Model code is quite simple since all it is a query statement with parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you are assigning events to users, I would make a hasOne relation in Event to Workflow.  You would need another relationship for you users, hasOne or hasMany.

```
$hasOne = 'Workflow';
```

Obviously this would mean that your Event table would have a column called wordflow_id and would be associated with a single row in your workflow.  In the controller I would call the Event with by the user.

```
$this->Event->findAllByUserId($user_id);
```

This should provide you with an array that might look something like this.

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [Event] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'blah',
            ...
        ),
        [User] => array(
            'id' => 1,
            'name' => 'Charles',
            ...
        ),
        [Workflow] => array(
            [0] => array(
                'id' => 1,
                'name' => 'more blagblagblag',
                ...
            ),
            [1] => array(
                'id' => 9,
                'name' => 'sblagblsagblag',
                ...
            ),
            [2] => array(
                'id' => 42,
                'name' => 'mordse d',
                ...
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Call all your workflow templates

```
$this->Workflow->find('all');
```

Then I would user cake's built in SET:: functionality to print the workflow template in your view and use your Event call to fill in the data.

Please post more detail and your code, models, ect and I'm sure we can get you the exact query/logic you'll need to achieve this.

http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/set.html

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question. I am able to retrieve all the data as necessary using `find` mehtods. However my question was around a design consideration - i.e where to embed the processing functionality - controller or view - found the answer though - thanks